# Tensorflow Error: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 177, 203) for Tensor u'Placeholder_3:0', which has shape '(?, 181, 192)'

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and I am receiving an error when I run this:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init

n_epochs = 1000
batch_size = 100
n_batches = len(train_sequences) // batch_size
print(n_batches)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        train_sequences, train_y, train_lengths = shuffle(train_sequences, train_y, train_lengths)
        for iteration in range(n_batches):
            start = iteration*batch_size
            end = start+batch_size
            X_batch = train_sequences[start:end]
            y_batch = train_y[start:end]
            seq_length_batch = train_lengths[start:end]
            if iteration % 20 == 0:
                train_summary_str = train_summary_op.eval(
                    feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
                )
                step = epoch * n_batches + iteration
                train_writer.add_summary(train_summary_str, step)
                train_writer.flush()

            if iteration % 200 == 0:
                summary_str = eval_summary_op.eval(
                    feed_dict = {X: test_sequences, y: test_y, seq_length: test_lengths}
                )
                step = epoch * n_batches + iteration
                eval_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
                eval_writer.flush()

            sess.run(
                training_op,
                feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
            )

        acc_train = accuracy.eval(
            feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
        )
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(
            feed_dict = {X: test_sequences, y: test_y, seq_length: test_lengths}
        )

        print(epoch, "Train accuracy:", acc_train, "Test accuracy:", acc_test)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/model.ckpt")

    train_writer.close()
    eval_writer.close()
```

The error I am receiving is:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 177, 203) for Tensor
>   u'Placeholder_3:0', which has shape '(?, 181, 192)'

It looks like this is where the error gets generated:

```
train_summary_str = train_summary_op.eval(
               feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
                  )
```

**UPDATE:**
I fixed the error by changing the dimensions whilst defining the tf placeholder.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
n_steps = 177
n_inputs = 203
n_neurons = 100
n_outputs = 2
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seq_length)
```

Comment: can you show the full code; specifically where are you defining your placeholder? and data load

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the graph you have defined, so we don't know what exactly training_op is supposed to do.

That said, I guess you have defined a placeholder X with shape [None, 181, 192] that you try to feed a value of shape [100, 177, 203]. I don't know what your input looks like, but judging from the shape it might be grayscale images. If your network is not fully convolutional, all input images must have the exact same shape which you then have to specify in the placeholder.

Try to rescale your images to the shape that the placeholder expects before feeding them to the graph.

Comment: I have fixed the error myself by changing the the dimensions as per the error. That is, n_steps is changed from 181 to 177 and n_inputs from 192 to 203. By the way, I am wondering, how do you pre-determine the n_steps and n_inputs. Here, I got it because the error said so!